# Database design: When not to use foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, entity-attribute-value

I am unsure what is the rule of thumb of when to use foreign keys and when it's better to insert an "unreferenced" value in regard of disk space needed, performance etc.

Let's say I have three tables:

Table 1: itemGroup (for to populate a dropdown menu with items)

```
ID  title   
1   Active/Inactive Options
2   Car Brands
3   Ratings
4   Languages
```

Table 2: item (the itemID will be the actual value in the dropdown and used as a foreign key )

```
itemID  listID  title   
1000    1       active
1001    1       inactive
1002    2       Porsche
1003    2       Audi
1004    3       1-Star Rating
1005    3       2-Star Rating 
1006    4       en 
1007    4       de
```

Table 3: exampleTable

```
ID  car rating active language
```

So my question is whether I should insert foreign keys in table 3 using the itemID, or would it make more sense to use a 1/0 for active/inactive and to use let's say 1,2,3,4,5 as an integer for the rating? Guess for the car it's quite self explaining that the foreign keys are better but in some cases it's hard to decide as my "item" table can be very big and therefore the itemID has more digits than the actual "value" it might be referring  to and in a big database this at some point will make a difference in space and I guess also performance wise because with foreign keys I need to make joints.

UPDATE:
I added the field "language" as maybe here the issue gets illustrated better. So if I'd store a language foreign key (e.g. "1006"):

- I need to store over and over a 4-digit int in my exampleTable, instead of just a 2-character varchar
- I can't do a an easy query like "SELECT * from exampleTable WHERE language=en"

Why would it be better to use a foreign key here?

Comment: Does the active/inactive state effect individual items or just the item group as a whole? If the latter, then I'd make that a boolean rather than making that a separate item in another table.  I don't think your issue is so much deciding on foreign key design but how to normalize the tables as a whole.

Comment: FKs are _not_ required by MySQL.  An FK does two things:  (1) provide a runtime constraint and (2) provide an `INDEX` if not already provided.  Indexes help with performance.

Comment: @Phaelaxz: In regard of active/inactive in many of my tables I would refer to item.itemID to mark a specific entry as active or inactive. So I think I agree that a boolean (mysql: unsigned tinyint(1)) is better in this case, right?

Comment: That's an "EAV" (Entity Attribute Value) schema.  It sucks, as you are finding out.  Follow the tag I added.